# Teams ServiceURL change its value with different data location

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

A couple of days it was working well the ServiceURL value is "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac" which was clearly the location is "APAC" but recently sometimes the ServiceURL value change to  "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/jp" and I believe this map for japan.

Comment: Could you please share the bot id?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I figure out the issue, in each user has its own service url and its by region. So what I did, I capture every user service url and used that for my ConnectionClient to send a conversation on teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding copying comments to answer
@Eze

For each user the the service url will be different based on the region. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

This is by region to improve the performance of requests.
(Just to add a little context to what @nikitha-msft said)